# Finding unique data from two columns

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL table where health check reports of many nodes are updated with, below is the sample table

```
Node Check    Status
   1 Network  Compliant
   1 Disk     Compliant
   1 Services Non-Compliant
   1 Memory   Compliant
   2 Network  Compliant
   2 Disk     Compliant
   2 Services Compliant    
   3 Memory   Compliant    
   3 Network  Compliant    
   3 Disk     Compliant    
   3 Services Compliant    
   3 Memory   Compliant    
   4 Network  Compliant    
   4 Disk     Compliant    
   4 Services Compliant    
   4 Memory   Compliant    
   5 Network  Non-Compliant    
   5 Disk     Compliant    
   5 Services Compliant    
   5 Memory   Compliant    
   6 Network  Compliant    
   6 Disk     Compliant    
   6 Services Compliant    
   6 Memory   Compliant
```

My requirement is to get below information

Count the total number of distinct Nodes, and then even if one check is failed for a Node on a given day mark the node as Non-Compliant and only if all checks on a given day are Compliant, then mark the node as compliant and show information as below

[image: Desired Result]

Thanks,

Comment: Please dont edit the question now. Especially dont replace formatted table with image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer to an earlier question:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(node INT NOT NULL
,metric ENUM('Network','Disk','Services','Memory') NOT NULL
,status ENUM('Compliant','Non-Compliant')
,PRIMARY KEY(node,metric)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'Network','Compliant'),
(1,'Disk','Compliant'),
(1,'Services','Non-Compliant'),
(1,'Memory','Compliant'),
(2,'Network','Compliant'),
(2,'Disk','Compliant'),
(2,'Services','Compliant'),
(2,'Memory','Compliant'),
(3,'Network','Compliant'),
(3,'Disk','Compliant'),
(3,'Services','Compliant'),
(3,'Memory','Compliant'),
(4,'Network','Compliant'),
(4,'Disk','Compliant'),
(4,'Services','Compliant'),
(4,'Memory','Compliant'),
(5,'Network','Non-Compliant'),
(5,'Disk','Compliant'),
(5,'Services','Compliant'),
(5,'Memory','Compliant'),
(6,'Network','Compliant'),
(6,'Disk','Compliant'),
(6,'Services','Compliant'),
(6,'Memory','Compliant');

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT x.node) total
     , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN y.node IS NULL THEN x.node END) compliant
     , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN y.node IS NOT NULL THEN x.node END) `non-compliant` 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y
    ON y.node = x.node 
   AND y.status = 'non-compliant';
+-------+-----------+---------------+
| total | compliant | non-compliant |
+-------+-----------+---------------+
|     6 |         4 |             2 |
+-------+-----------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

We can first determine the "full compliant" status for every `Node` in a Derived Table. Then, we can use this result-set to get total counts.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS total_nodes, 
  SUM(fully_compliant = 0) AS Non_compliant_nodes, 
  SUM(fully_compliant = 1) AS compliant_nodes 
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    Node,
    CASE WHEN SUM(Status = 'Compliant') = COUNT(*) THEN 1
         ELSE 0
    END AS fully_compliant 
  FROM your_table
  GROUP BY Node 
) AS dt
```

**Result**

```
| total_nodes | Non_compliant_nodes | compliant_nodes |
| ----------- | ------------------- | --------------- |
| 6           | 2                   | 4               |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gF3X2bwDiBC9LKgjgWUfS3/0)

Comment: Hi Madhur, Your solution worked perfectly, thanks for the help. I have edited the my post to reflect one more column and challenge, can you advice on any good way to achieve that

Comment: @Bharath please dont change question now. You can post it as a new question. I will be happy to help you there.

Answer (score -1):

```
select count(distinct Node) as TotalNodes, SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN status='non_compliant' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NonComp,SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN status='compliant' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Comp from Table;
```

Comment: Thanks, i have a new challenge, edited the question to reflect new data, please advice me on the way to achieve desired output

Comment: count(distinct Node) = number of nodes,
SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN status='non_compliant' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NonComp = number of noncompliant.